# Since upgrade from Magento 2.1 to 2.2 I have localization erros on my module

Tags: magento2

i have a problem with a custom module, since the upgrade from 2.1 to 2.2 all my messages in the Controller and Emails won't get translated.

Example:
Module_Questions -> Controller -> Index -> Index.php

there I have a messageManager and use translation with success message

```
    "__('Mail sent')"
```

but it is displayed on the frontend as:

```
    "{{{Mail sent}}{{Mail sent}}{{Mail sent}}{{theme2}}}"
```

and the same for emails. I have currently no idea why it doesn't work.

Would appreciate any help.